# C++17 problems with Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: c++, c++17, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been trying to set up CI/CD in the repo for a library I am working on. It requires C++17 and successfully compiles on my local machine. However, when the pipeline runs on Gitlab, when it compiles I get this error.

```
 $ make check
 Scanning dependencies of target gtest
 [  9%] Building CXX object googletest-build/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest- 
 all.cc.o
 [ 18%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libgtest.a
 [ 18%] Built target gtest
 Scanning dependencies of target mconf
 [ 27%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mconf.dir/src/config_option.cpp.o
 [ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mconf.dir/src/config_file.cpp.o
 In file included from /builds/USER/config_parser/src/config_file.cpp:1:0:
 /builds/USER/config_parser/src/config_file.hpp:9:10: fatal error: filesystem: No 
 such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
 compilation terminated.
 CMakeFiles/mconf.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 
 'CMakeFiles/mconf.dir/src/config_file.cpp.o' failed
 make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/mconf.dir/src/config_file.cpp.o] Error 1
 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:100: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mconf.dir/all' failed
 make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mconf.dir/all] Error 2
 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/check.dir/rule' failed
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/check.dir/rule] Error 2
 Makefile:175: recipe for target 'check' failed
 make: *** [check] Error 2
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
image: ubuntu:latest

stages:
    - build

before_script:
    - apt update -qq

Build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - apt install -y -qq cmake make git gcc g++
        - mkdir build
        - cd build
        - cmake ..
        - make check
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - public
```

I also have not changed any of the settings for CI/CD on Gitlab. I tried using debian:stable, but I just got a linker error to the functions I'm using from filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

> The ubuntu:latest tag points to the "latest LTS", since that's the
>   version recommended for general use. The ubuntu:rolling tag points to
>   the latest release (regardless of LTS status).

At the time of writing, `ubuntu:latest` corresponds to Ubuntu 18.04 release, which might be too old.

Try `ubuntu:rolling`, which currently corresponds to Ubuntu 19.10.